# Symfony 2 an error occurred when executing the "composer install" command

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

**Symfony 2.4**

When I run `composer install` I see such errors:

```
Generating autoload files

Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ClearCache\CollectionRegionCommand' not found in /Users/vpx/www/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Command/Proxy/CollectionRegionDoctrineCommand.php on line 29
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

After changes in the composer.json from `"doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3"` to `"doctrine/orm": "~2.2.3"` all right. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did change the versions in a way you probably didn't see.

```
"doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3"
```

This allows versions starting from 2.2.3 (last restriction), going up to not include 3.0, but 2.9999.9999.

```
"doctrine/orm": "~2.2.3"
```

This allows versions starting from 2.2.3, going up to not include 2.3.0, but 2.2.9999.

So your change effectively disallows the versions 2.3.* and up now, which might be the reason for the failure, because that particular library already has release version 2.4.2, which is now disallowed.

You probably should update that version requirement, because it seems like the post-install command that executes some updates does not work with version 2.2.x of this library. I'd suggest using at least `~2.3` as this will also exclude versions 2.2.2 and below as done previously.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `composer update` instead of `composer install`.

If that doesn't work, try replacing `"doctrine/orm": "~2.3.3"` with `"doctrine/orm": "dev-master"` in `composer.json`.

Comment: Never use branches if you can avoid it. It will make things worse.